# Determine if the current user has active debug logs turned on

Tags: apex, debug

In apex, can you dynamically check if the current user has an active debug session (i.e. Setup -> Monitoring -> Debug Logs)?

I looked at the DebuggingHeader, but it doesn't quite do the trick

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/sforce_api_header_debuggingheader.htm?search_text=debuggingHeader

Answer (score 0):

Sure we can use the below query:

```
SELECT Id,TracedEntityId FROM TraceFlag where TracedEntity.type = 'user'
```

also, you can run the query without any conditions and filter various traceflags by iteration after a null check on them..

Comment: Thanks... can you use TraceFlag in Apex, or is when you're using the Tooling API?

Comment: I was able to use it in apex execution it worked fine for me ☺️